# Displays Site's and Facebook's posts in my Application

Tags: java, android

I am wondering about this technique, which I can display my site's posts and Facebook wall's posts together in my application, like an application I saw that displays a site's wall posts and Facebook page posts as a Cardview.

Here is a Screenshot of the app that displays the site's posts:
[image: Gamers Field application with 2 posts]

Here is another screenshot of displaying their Facebook page's wall posts:
[image: Gamers Field application with 2 different posts]

I would like to know how to do this technique.
What is the name of the function and object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use facebook API. Facebook Api such as [Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api). 
For that

1.Sign in as a [developer.facebook.com](http://developer.facebook.com) and it will provide api key which you should add in your application dependency.

1. The Graph API is the primary way to get data in and out of Facebook's platform. you should make use of the sdk
2. Make use of graph api reference in its documentation page.
3. For more specific as android application facebook provide [graph api for android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/graph).
4. For the website you should create your own api. There are many ways and languages to accompolish this but i prefer rails 5 api feature to do this.
5. Create rails 5 as a [backend](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html)
6. You the json data which is generated by the rails application to mobile app.

Hope this make sense!!